# AppController alternative for Cocos2d 3.0

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Here is my Cocos2d 2.0 calls. What's alternative for this in Cocos2d 3.0

```
    AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [[app navController] presentModalViewController:achivementViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

In Cocos2d 3.0, use CCAppDelegate instead of AppController:

```
CCAppDelegate *app = (CCAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[[app navController] presentModalViewController:achivementViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

AppController is again renamed to AppDelegate:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

AppDelegate * app = (((AppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate));

[[app navController] presentModalViewController:achivementViewController animated:YES];
```